# How to get the value of two selected options using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following select options:

```
<select id="optionA">
<option> A </option>
<option> B </option>
<option> C </option>
</select>

<select id="optionB">
<option> D </option>
<option> E </option>
<option> F </option>
</select>
```

The following jquery code is not working to determine the text values of each selected options:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
            if($("#optionA").change() || ($("#optionB").change())
            {
                var textA = $(this).find("#optionA option:selected").text();
                var textB = $(this).find("#optionB option:selected").text();
                alert( + textA + " " + textB);
            }
        });
</script>
```

Any idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#optionA, #optionB').change(function()
{
    alert($('#optionA').val() + ' ' + $('#optionB').val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/upZKt/1/

Comment: This is the best solution because I can replace the alert function and associate it option A and B with a file name.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the following:

```
<select id="optionA">
  <option value="A"> A </option>
  <option value="B"> B </option>
  <option value="C"> C </option>
</select>

<select id="optionB">
  <option value="D"> D </option>
  <option value="E"> E </option>
  <option value="F"> F </option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectChanged() {
        var textA = $("#optionA").val();
        var textB = $("#optionB").val();
        alert(textA + " " + textB);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#optionA,#optionB").change(selectChanged);
    });
</script>
```

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/crnrY/

Comment: Thanks aroth, your code was the only one I could get to work based on my question.

Comment: I don't see a big green check mark - make sure you accept aroth's answer if it worked for you so he can get his points and recognition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your event handlers like this:

```
$("#optionA,#optionB").change(function() {
   var textA = $("#optionA").val();
   var textB = $("#optionB").val();
   alert( + textA + " " + textB);
});
```

Comment: No need to look at the option, only the select val()

Comment: @AlienWebguy You are right, I had just copied&pasted irrelevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

[`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) takes a callback function as an event handler when the *change* event fires.

You need to move the code from within your if `block` to a callback function. **Note:** I've also condensed the selector and logic to utilize more of the jQuery style.

```
$("#optionA, #optionB").change(function() {
    var textA = $("#optionA").val();
    var textB = $("#optionB").val();
    alert(textA + " " + textB);
});
```

See it in action - http://jsfiddle.net/G4Lpm/1/

Comment: @AlienWebguy, I know. See my **note**.

Comment: I see it, but it doesn't do what he asked, which was to show both select values.

Comment: No worries :) New user with 1 point I doubt any of us will get any points from this thread anyhow haha